Проблема с установкой Qt Creator на MacOs
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: зашёл на офф. сайт Qt, чтобы установить creator на макбук, появилась такая штука: Qt Maintenance Tool. Внутри данного приложения я авторизовался, выбрал компоненты для работы с C++ и непосредственно всё установил. По окончании загрузки никаких проблем не было, кроме того, что приложения Qt creator у меня так и не появилось, его нет ни в загрузках, ни в прилогах, но он установлен, вопрос: что делать? Как ярлык отобразить?

Вообще говоря, Qt прекратило поддержку работы Maintenance Tool на территории РФ. Определят местоположение по ip и в итоге ничего не устанавливается. Сообщения не было вида "ip address not supported?"

Кьют на маке по дефолту ставится в /users/username/Qt, проверьте там. по идее спотлайт должен без проблем его там находить
